# Returning multilpe values from model method in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following method in my model:

```
  def self.set_bad_recommedation_size(rating_set)
    bad = Rating.where(rating_set: rating_set).where(label: 'Bad').count
    total = Rating.where(rating_set: rating_set).count
    percentage_bad = (bad.to_f/total.to_f * 100)
    return bad, total, percentage_bad
  end
```

How do I call the variable bad, total, percentage_bad in my view.
What I want:

```
<%= "#{Model.set_bad_recommedation_size(rating_set).bad}/#{Model.set_bad_recommedation_size(rating_set).total"%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off doing:

```
<% bad, total, percentage_bad = Model.set_bad_recommedation_size(rating_set) %>
<%= "#{bad}/#{total}" %>
```

That way you're not calling the method multiple times.

Comment: Even though this works, its always a good idea to seperate the model functions and views. Harish has a better better answer I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I would add an intermediate helper so that your view reads better

```
<%= bad_recommendation_ratio(result_set) %>
```

Application.helper

```
def bad_recommendation_ratio(result_set)
  bad, total = Model.set_bad_recommedation_size(rating_set)
  "#{bad}/#{total}"
end
```